# App Crashes When Something done in onCreate (That is not declarations or initialization)but not in onClick

Tags: java, android

I am creating a calculator.As you know it has many buttons I wanted to resize according to screen sizes.I put the code in my onCreate but it just crashed.I put it in OnClickListner, it worked.I want it to happen when we start the activity.How do I fix it?

I first did it in a separate class, then a separate function in MainActivity.java.Then in onCreate.Then in OnClickListner.

I accessed everything from onCreate in the first 3 attempts.

This is my code for resizing it in onClickListner--

```java
findViewById(R.id.btnfix).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);Button btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);Button btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);Button btnsqrt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sqrt);Button btnexpo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.expo);Button btncb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cb);Button btnob = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ob);Button btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);Button btnsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);Button btnmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);Button btndiv =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);Button btnclr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clr);Button btnlog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log);


                DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
                int width = dm.widthPixels;
                int btnw = width/4;

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn1.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn1.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn2.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn2.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn3.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn3.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn4.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn4.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn5.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn5.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn6.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn6.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn7.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn7.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn8.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn8.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn9.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn9.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn0.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btn0.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnadd.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnadd.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnsub.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnsub.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnmul.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnmul.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btndiv.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btndiv.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnsqrt.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnsqrt.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnexpo.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnexpo.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnob.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnob.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btncb.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btncb.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnlog.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnlog.setLayoutParams(params);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnclr.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = btnw;
                btnclr.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
```

And this in onCreate only--

```java
@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        errorMessageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_message);
        errorMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);Button btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);Button btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);Button btnsqrt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sqrt);Button btnexpo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.expo);Button btncb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cb);Button btnob = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ob);Button btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);Button btnsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);Button btnmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);Button btndiv =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);Button btnclr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clr);Button btnlog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log);


        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int btnw = width/4;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn1.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn1.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn2.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn2.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn3.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn3.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn4.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn4.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn5.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn5.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn6.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn6.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn7.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn7.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn8.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn8.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn9.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn9.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn0.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btn0.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnadd.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnadd.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnsub.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnsub.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnmul.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnmul.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btndiv.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btndiv.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnsqrt.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnsqrt.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnexpo.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnexpo.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnob.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnob.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btncb.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btncb.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnlog.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnlog.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnclr.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = btnw;
        btnclr.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I tried n number of times, but only worked in onClickListner.It crashed elsetime

Comment: how does your onCreate look like?

Comment: Where is the onCreate? What is the logcat output?

Comment: What is the LogCat? I will edit the question right now

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you are trying to get the LayoutParams when the layout has not been created yet. Try adding Post to your parent layout and do your logic in there.

For example

```
parentLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    //your code here 
    }
   });
```

Comment: what should be the parentLayout in my case?Would it be LinearLayout?

Comment: I used a onResume override method and it did it for me.